# What is the difference of buying Coca-Cola shares from the NYSE vs Xetra?

Tags: stocks, dividends, germany, nyse

What is the difference of buying Coca-Cola shares from the NYSE vs Xetra?

I understand that the NYSE is in USD and Xetra is in EUR but the question here is about risks, dividends, and any other factors, because I see the price is the same but the currency is different.

Comment: *Must* there be any difference other than "one's in the US for US buyers" while "the other is in Europe for European buyers"?

Comment: Makes sense but Europe buyers can buy from US as well that is why I'm asking :)

Comment: Then I should rephrase my question: *Must* there be any difference other than "one's in the US denominated in USD" while "the other is in Europe denominated in EUR"?

Answer (score -1):

Their dividend yields are the same, per Yahoo! Finance:

[NYSE:KO](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/KO?p=KO)

[ETR:CCC3](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/CCC3.DE/)